# How do I 'write' the contents of my text boxes back to my Dictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

Here is my code so far...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            Dictionary<string, TextBox> DTB = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
            Dictionary<string, decimal> Numbers = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();


            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                Numbers.Add("Price 1", 0.01M);
                Numbers.Add("Price 2", 0.05M);
                Numbers.Add("Price 3", 0.09M);
                int sizecount = 0;
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, decimal> kvp in Numbers)
                {
                    DTB.Add(kvp.Key, new TextBox());
                    DTB[kvp.Key].Text = kvp.Value.ToString();
                    DTB[kvp.Key].Top =sizecount * 30;
                    this.Controls.Add(DTB[kvp.Key]);
                    sizecount++;
                }

            }

            private void btnWriteBackToNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
```

And an image of my form, I want to change the values here and have them 'write' back to the Numbers Dictionary when the button is clicked.

[image: Sample Form]

I started by storing the Dictionary keys with in the text box name and then using this to identify 'where' to put the values in the Numbers Dictionary, but this was long winded and felt wrong, There must be a simpler way?

I need the code to put in this method...

```
private void btnWriteBackToNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would work. I'm pretty much just reversing what you're doing when you copy the values to the textboxes.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, TextBox> textbox in DTB)
{
    Numbers[textbox.Key] = Convert.ToDecimal(textbox.Value.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes but how do I know which text box has changed?

Comment: It wouldn't really matter, if the textbox hasn't changed, the data in kvp and DTB will be the same anyways.

Comment: I am not getting this,  If I change the values on a text box I want it to write back to the Numbers dictonary, so I need the code to put in the private void btnWriteBackToNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote, I have edited the answer, I definitely meant to write to Numbers dictionary. Yes, in btnWriteBackToNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e).

Comment: This works after I edited it. Please see edits.Thanks very much.  I will accept it once the edit has been approved.